# More advanced alternatives to Trajectory Optimization Tool?

Tags: mission-design, lagrangian-points, gravity-assist, software, trajectory-design

I've been using Arrowstar's [Trajectory Optimization Tool](https://www.orbiter-forum.com/threads/trajectory-optimization-tool-v2-1.21998/) to plan interplanetary transfers, and it works well. The next thing I want to do is plan gravity assists from the Sun-Earth L2 Lagrange point to the Earth before going to other destinations, or various Earth-Moon trajectories. However, TOT has the limitation that it is only able to compute interplanetary (Sun-centered) trajectories, so that it isn't an option. Moreover, while it has the option of adding custom bodies with SPICE kernels, the ones available [here](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/lagrange_point/) for the Lagrange points I want are centered at the Earth-Moon barycenter, not the Sun.

So is there a more advanced software that can do what TOT does, that is, solve Lambert's problem and use patched conics for quick trajectory approximations for bodies of choice, with user-defined constraints? I have tried to create GMAT scripts to calculate launch windows and gravity assists and the like, but I don't think its optimizer is meant to do that, since it uses gradient descent which relies on feasible initial values/assumptions. I saw an answer here mention a software similar to TOT that NASA uses to get a first impression into the windows and date opportunities that are available for transfers between bodies in the solar system before they do more in-depth trajectory design, but I can't find it even after searching with multiple terms.